# how to customize DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android

i want to customize DatePickerDialog. My core objective is to change the theme of whole DatePickerDialog.

is this possible to customize the theme of DatePickerDialog.

if this not possible then i want the sample code for any date picker.

Comment: Similar question... maybe it will help a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958606/how-to-customize-datepickerdialog

Comment: @rlc It's a link to here...

Answer (score 2):

You try set style for it

style

```
<style name="MyPickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Set style for dialog

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.MyPickerDialog);
dialog.show();
```

Hope this help.